# React - Lifecycle and use of ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

I am working on a full stack react project - node backend with graphql and apollo on the front.  It is a simplified clone of you tube.  With react router I have a route `/video/${video-id}`. I parse the id and use apollo to pull the information from an mlab database, including the url to the video file on aws s3. Anyways, I had set up some functionality in `componentDidMount` - including the increment to the total views, adjusting the video to a certain time, etc. Now this was working great when I was linking to videos from my `/channel` route...

I ran into a problem when I set up a video list. Imagine youtube, with 75% of the screen is the video and 25% is a vertical list of thumbnail links. Now when I click on thumbnails everything works on the surface, but since the video url is just a piece of state componentDidMount is not fired and a lot of the functions I want to fire are not fired.

What should I do. I'm not sure what supplying code would do to help, this is more of a lifecycle question, or I guess a big picture react strategy question. Right now I am looking into other lifecycle functions - possibly adding a conditional to detect a change in the url for the video and then executing these certain functions I want on a per video basis.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `componentDidUpdate` in addition to `componentDidMount`. If the component has the video ID as `this.state.videoId`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.videoId !== this.state.videoId) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: The `key` approach looks simpler, but this `componentDidUpdate` approach has some pros. With it, the video component is more self-contained because you don’t need to remember to set `key` to make it work properly. Also, it won’t be a big deal, but it reuses the same DOM elements when video is changed while the `key`approach throws away and recreates DOM elements. And I believe the running cost of `componentDidUpdate` is almost nothing because it only compares two values while it is showing the same video.

Comment: I wonder how far is too far when breaking down react components.  i have my route or main component getting the data and then try to break that down into manageable pieces.  The way I had it I would have needed to pass state and props down two times(to take the key approach) which ends up being a lot to keep track of at a certain point.

Comment: You're nesting component too far when it starts to slow down your productivity, at which point you can consider using Redux or similar to allow the children components to directly access some `state` from a global store. @ShuheiKagawa is right about the running cost being trivial for `componentDidUpdate` and it can be a solid first approach. Sometimes `componentDidUpdate` can be unwieldy if it has too much logic, at which point rearranging components is another solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If possible you can make the video into another component, let's say the `<VideoComponent />` while still storing the url in the parent component's state.

When rendering the video component, give it the url as a key and this will trigger the video component's `componentDidMount` life cycle method on every change of the url value.

Usage: `<VideoComponent key={this.state.url} />`

I prefer this over using `componentDidUpdate` since it only get executed one time whereas in `componentDidUpdate` it will be re-evaluated on any change, even unrelated changes to the component.

Comment: seems logical and efficient